# Sonar for Raspberry Pi

Tags: hardware

I would like to make a bathymetric map (depths) of a lake. So i'm thinking of using a Raspberry Pi connected to a GPS and sonar. Is there a echosounder/sonar device that can be connected to a Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for NMEA depth sounder, there are plenty of them.
You should then be able to plot it out using OpenCPN, or convert and overlay on Google Earth or similar.